# Why WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK returns false?

Tags: c#

I use this code to verify Twitter email and password in c# but it return false and I do not know why?
also, I want to return the xml to read the username from it.

```
bool Result = false;

// A try except block to handle any exceptions
try
{
    // Encode the user name with password
    string UserPass = Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email + ":" + password));

    // Create our HTTP web request object
    HttpWebRequest Request =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml");

    //Request.Proxy = WebProxy;
    //Request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    //Request.ReadWriteTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    //Request.KeepAlive = false;
    //Request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // was true
    //Request.CookieContainer = cc;
    //Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";

    // Set up our request flags and submit type
    Request.Method = "GET";
    Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Add the authorization header with the encoded user name and password
    Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + UserPass);

    // Use an HttpWebResponse object to handle the response from Twitter
    HttpWebResponse WebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

    string SourceCode = new StreamReader(WebResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    // Success if we get an OK response
    Result = WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + Ex.Message);
}

// Return success/failure

return Result;
```

Comment: Please make some effort to format your code - look at the preview before you post, and ask if that's really how you want your post to look. Next, presumably `Result` is false because `WebResponse.StatusCode` *isn't* `HttpStatusCode.OK`. Did you debug into the code and look at what it actually *is*? As an aside, local variables in C# conventionally start with a lower-case letter. Following conventions makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: As Jon mentions, you might want to review the Microsoft Naming Guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: thank you, I will make that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code returns 404 not found, which comes to the catch , so by default you are setting the result to false, it never reaches this line

```
result = WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

so the result is **`false`**;

Also to make it good practice declare your Result like this,

```
bool result = false;
```

Instead of

```
  result = WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

just do

```
if(WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;)
{
  result =true;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but still return 404 not found

Comment: Yes then it will return false only, mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: Please, I want to know why it returns 404 not found ?

Comment: Sure I will provide a sample